# Troubleshooting MySQL Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new table which has always been pretty easy in the past. This time I am trying to increase the quality of the way I do things by researching the collation I use as the default for my table. After reading a bit I decided `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` was the way to go.

At this point I create a table with 11 rows. Everytime I try and submit it tells me,

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
') NOT NULL , `password` INT(10000) NOT NULL , `hash` VARCHAR(10000) NOT 
NULL ,' at line 1
```

I have never had auto generated sql give me an error before. So,  I think this has to do with the coalition I chose. Also it appears to have a problem close to my double. Which leads me to believe I can't use the collation I am using with a `Double`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

```
    CREATE TABLE `skel`.`accounts` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
, `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`first` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `last` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `phone` 
VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `rate` 
DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL , `hash` 
VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL , `confirmed` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY 
(`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Is double with without precision specification legal? Also, what are you thinking `int(10000)` accomplishes?

Comment: the 10000 int is an accident.

Comment: Why do you think the problem has anything to do with collation? Collation doesn't change MySQL syntax rules.

Comment: I was not sure why the problem was happening. Per the reason I asked the question. I have never paid attention to the collation before it was the only thing I changed and as far as for the double being a stupid question "which you have all made your point very well" I just was not thinking obviously.

Answer (score 4):

`DOUBLE(20)` is not a valid data type.  In MySQL, `double` requires both scale and precision to be specified (if either is).  This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html).

So, specifying something like `DOUBLE(20, 5)` should be acceptable.

Also, `INT(10000)` doesn't really make sense.  You don't need the length specifier, but perhaps you intend `INT(5)` (5 digits of precision).  Or perhaps you should use `DECIMAL()` for the column.

Comment: He's edited the question to remove `INT(10000)`. That was clearly a mistake, since no one would use an integer for a password.